# Select based on item within an array

Tags: mysql, database, arrays

I am looking for a mySQL command to select rows based on whether or not an array field contains a specific item with that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure whether you want to find an item in an array stored in the DB or you want to find all rows that match an item in an array.

For the former (given that MySQL doesn't support array types natively I'm assuming you're doing something to serialize the data into a string column or the like):

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [table] WHERE [array_column] LIKE "%{separator}[test_value]{separator}%"; 
e.g. SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE values_list LIKE "%|5|%";
```

will do the job (where separator is whatever character you're using to separate values stored into the string column - e.g. given an array [0, 5, 10, 15] and a separator "|" the serialized string would be "|0|5|10|15|")

For the second case:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [table] WHERE [test_column] IN (list, of, some, values);
e.g. SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_value IN (0, 5, 10, 15);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure which I want. I need to `SELECT entries FROM table WHERE arrayfield CONTAINS my_value`, if that makes more sense?

Comment: The first one is the one you want then (i.e `SELECT [columns] FROM [table] WHERE [array_column] LIKE "%{separator}[test_value]{separator}%"; `)

Comment: Not quite working, here is the array as seen in mySQL `a:3:{i:0;s:3:"383";i:1;s:3:"409";i:2;s:3:"410";}`

Comment: I am after the 3 digit number strings

Comment: okay based on that I'd suggest that as all the 3 digit number strings are prefixed with "s:3:" you use something like `SELECT entries FROM table WHERE arrayfield LIKE "%s:3:\"410\"%"` substituting 410 for whatever number you're searching for